# Can you use props on React.Fragment?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-fragment

I know that a React Fragment can be used to group child components like this:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Foo />
      <Bar />
      <Baz />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

But can you add props to it? Say you want to use the spread operator:

```js
<React.Fragment {...otherProps}>
  ...
</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you can't. As per the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) on Fragments:

> key is the only attribute that can be passed to Fragment. In the future, we may add support for additional attributes, such as event handlers.

Therefore, if you want to add props to a wrapper component, switch to a good ol' div.

Comment: You just answered your own question as per another person's answer lol

Comment: @dev_junwen haha, I typed the question then randomly noticed that caveat in the React docs. Thought to proceed with asking it instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all because if you think to pass props like this -

```
<React.Fragment {...otherProps}>
....
<React.Fragment />
```

it means

```
< {...otherProps}>
</>
```

Which isn't right and Reactjs doesn't recommend using it like this.